# Need help in php regarding file post variables.

Tags: php, variables, file-upload

Hey guys i have 2 scripts with me for file upload.

One is amazon s3 upload script. Using this script i can upload from computer. Another one is normal remote upload script.

I would like to implement remote upload feature in amazon s3.

This is the code what i have in "direct upload script".

Html code

```
h1>Upload a file</h1>
<p>Please select a file by clicking the 'Browse' button and press 'Upload' to start uploading your file.</p>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
      <input name="theFile" type="file" />
      <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
```

PHP code to retreive post variables

```
$fileName = $_FILES['theFile']['name'];
$fileTempName = $_FILES['theFile']['tmp_name'];
```

My remote upload script code is as follows.

```
<form method="POST" action="<?=$self?>">
<input type="text" name="file[]"  size="45" value="">
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="submit"></p>
</form>
```

php code to receive files

```
$files = $_POST['file'];
```

This is my question. How to convert my remote upload code

> $files = $_POST['file'];

into

> $fileName = $_FILES['theFile']['name'];
>       $fileTempName = $_FILES['theFile']['tmp_name'];

Hope you guys get my point. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the `enctype` parameter on the `<form>` tag:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="__URL__" method="POST">
```

Some more help is in the PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

See specifically the second example.